# Are there any examples or tutorials on how you can use a URL SCHEME for Line by Naver?

Tags: android, url-scheme

I am trying to create an application that would connect itself to Line and allow it to post messages and stamps to the user's account.

I tried searching and I did see a library from Naver itself but all the documentations are either blank or in Korean. Thus, I don't know where to start. There are also scant examples on the net.

Have anybody here tried doing the same thing as I am? I would be really grateful and thankful if you would shed some light on this! :)

Answer (score 1):

Check http://media.line.me/howto/en/

You can basically share text or images to someone in your contacts or post it in your home.

Comment: but i want to open chat screen of specific user in line. is there any url scheme for that?

Comment: Seems like there's no solution to that in Line